# XOR Hex String in JAVA of different length

Tags: java, cryptography

I have two strings

```
String s1="426F62";
String s2="457665";
```

The strings are in hex representation. I want to XOR them. XORing normally character by character gives the correct result for others except `F XOR 6`.(It gives 112, the answer should be 9)

Please tell me the correct way to implement it in JAVA

EDIT: Converting to int and xoring works. But how to xor when two strings are of different length.

Comment: Only you can decide what it means to XOR strings of different length. Most likely you'll want to pad (at least conceptually) the shorter string with zeros, but you have to decide whether to pad on the left or the right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than XORing the *Unicode* representations, just convert each character into the number it represents in hex, XOR those, then convert it back to hex. You can still do that one character at a time:

```
public String xorHex(String a, String b) {
    // TODO: Validation
    char[] chars = new char[a.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = toHex(fromHex(a.charAt(i)) ^ fromHex(b.charAt(i)));
    }
    return new String(chars);
}

private static int fromHex(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    }
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    }
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

private char toHex(int nybble) {
    if (nybble < 0 || nybble > 15) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(nybble);
}
```

Note that this should work however long the strings are (so long as they're the same length) and never needs to worry about negative values - you'll always just get the result of XORing each pair of characters.

Comment: Nice way. XORing character by character is better way. But what about xoring two strings with different length. How we can do it?

Comment: @AndroidDecoded: You've have to define what you even *meant* by that to start with. Do you want to just cycle through when you got to the end of the shorter one, for example? (It should be pretty easy to do that.)

Comment: Like your idea to xor char by char but implemented in different way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String s1 = "426F62";
String s2 = "457665";
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1, 16);
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2, 16);
int n3 = n1 ^ n2;
String s3 = String.format("%06x", n3);
```

Why are you storing hex values as strings? it'd be a much better idea to represent hex numbers as hex integers or longs.

Comment: That solves the problem. But while xoring 4 XOR 4, the result is 0 which is lost when we store it in integer n3. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: With the above code, making s1="4" and s2="4", s3 will be "0", as expected. I don't understand why you say it's "lost".

Comment: When xoring the result should be "071907" but as it is stored in integer, it would be represented as "71907". First 0 is lost.

Comment: I edited my answer, now the printed results will always have 6 characters in length, padding with 0s to the left if necessary. Try it, you can adapt that solution for your needs (for instance, if you want to preserve the same number of characters from the input strings). Notice that the algorithm is fine, adding 0s to the left is just a presentation problem that can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that it gives correct result is an artifact of the particular character encoding for digits and letters. You should convert the numbers to `BigInteger`, `XOR` them, and convert back to `String`:

```
BigInteger i1 = new BigInteger(s1, 16);
BigInteger i2 = new BigInteger(s2, 16);
BigInteger res = i1.xor(i2);
String s3 = res.toString(16);
```

**EDIT** (in response to Jon Skeet's comment): Using `BigInteger` instead of `int` to address the four-byte limit issue.

Comment: This assumes only 4 bytes, and also negative handling could be interesting.

Comment: @JonSkeet The example uses only 3 bytes, but the "cryptography" tag suggests it's probably a rather shortened example. I added a longer and much slower solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet I replaced `int` with `BigInteger` to address the four-byte limitation. Thanks!

Comment: What does that do in terms of being negative? I'd still suggest just going char by char, personally...

Comment: @JonSkeet It sidesteps the problem of being negative, because `toString(16)` [formats negative numbers as expected](http://ideone.com/kzizv).

Comment: I suppose actually it'll never be negative anyway, given that BigInteger has arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that could be helpful depending on the size of the strings

```
String s1="426F62";
String s2="457665";

BigInteger one = new BigInteger(s1, 16);
BigInteger two = new BigInteger(s2, 16);
BigInteger three = one.xor(two);
```

Comment: Thats a nice way. But how we will xor two strings of different length. Unexpected results by this method.

Comment: This is not about the length of the strings but about the orders of magnitude of the numbers. I'd assume the two numbers must be of the same order of magnitude before xoring them. Can you please provide an example of the "unexpected results" that you mention so that I can understand better what the problem would be?